# Implement Restful WCF OData Service

Tags: json, wcf, odata, wcf-rest

I've implemented a WCF OData Service in my project.  Right now I need to my services return JsonResult for my clients.  How can I implement Restful WCF OData Service? Or is there any alternative approach to return JsonResult in my services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OData Services natively support JSON. So if in the HTTP Request header you are specifying following header, you would always get JSON

> accept: application/json

If you can not control the this, then I suggest you to use $format filter.

For example See http://odata.netflix.com/v2/Catalog/Genres?$Format=json

JSONp and URL-controlled format support for ADO.NET Data Services download from MSDN http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/DataServicesJSONP and add the JSONPSupportBehavior decorator to your DataService class like below.

```
[JSONPSupportBehavior]
public class SomeService: DataService<ContextType>
{
```

The other option could be to build ASP.NET Web API. Its an ideal platform for building RESTful applications on the .NET Framework.